# bootstrap pictures + text positioning?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to position Pictures and Text in bootstrap Grid. I have 4 columns with pictures and I am trying to display a text on their right side.

Currently this is the code I am using:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-1 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <div class="holder">
    <img class="img" src="apple.png">   
    <span class="text">Some text</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-2 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <div class="holder">
    <img class="img" src="apple.png">   
    <span class="text">Some text</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-2 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <div class="holder">
    <img class="img" src="apple.png">   
    <span class="text">Some text</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-2 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <div class="holder">
    <img class="img" src="apple.png">   
    <span class="text">Some text</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The pictures are positioned proper but somehow I can't position the text to stay on the right side of each picture.

Has to be like: |img|text |img|text |img|text |img|text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <div class="holder">
      <img class="img" src="apple.png">
      <span class="text">Some text</span> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <div class="holder">
      <img class="img" src="apple.png">
      <span class="text">Some text</span> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <div class="holder">
      <img class="img" src="apple.png">
      <span class="text">Some text</span> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <div class="holder">
      <img class="img" src="apple.png">
      <span class="text">Some text</span> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Did you try this?

Comment: @StillMoJo: yeah... Actually the text comes besides the image, but it doesnt get enough space to accomodate itself... So, if you don't need the offset, then probably u can use that space by giving ur images enough space. :)

Comment: this worked good but got another issue, the text is consisted of 2 words, when I try to use <br> to make the secound word go in other row, it goes under the image, any ideas?

Comment: @StillMoJo: lemme give it a try... Maybe then I can come up with one... :)

Comment: <span class="text">{{text.text_Ftext}}<br>{{text.text_Ltext}}</span> It's like that

Comment: <div class="holder">
          <img class="img col-lg-6" src="apple.png" />
          <div>
            <span class="text col-lg-6">Some <br/> text</span>
          </div>
        </div>

Comment: and depending on ur requirement, you can change the value of inner "col-lg's"

Comment: @StillMoJo: Glad, I could help... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with Pull-right class in span:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-1 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <div class="holder">
    <img class="img" src="apple.png">   
    <span class="text pull-right">Some text</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-2 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <div class="holder">
    <img class="img" src="apple.png">   
    <span class="text pull-right">Some text</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-2 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <div class="holder">
    <img class="img" src="apple.png">   
    <span class="text pull-right">Some text</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-2 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <div class="holder">
    <img class="img" src="apple.png">   
    <span class="text pull-right">Some text</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pull-right doesn't work, because the text is still under the image even with set display: inline; to the text class